# Is it true :$f(f^{-1}(C))=C? $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$  and $C$ be a subset   of $ Y.$ Is the following  hold:

$f(f^{-1}(C))=C? $

If it is wrong then what is right answer?

As for me $f(f^{-1}(C)) \subseteq C.$

Comment: No. Take a simple function on the reals that isn't a bijection: $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Also note that $f^{-1}(f(C))$ is not even defined.

Comment: What would $f(C)$ mean here?

Comment: I think  it means the image of  the map

Comment: The point is that it doesn't make sense, since $C \subseteq Y$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Leox You can still formulate a similar statement. Cf my answer for detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition for $C\subset X$
$$f^{-1}(f(C)) = \{x\in X | f(x) \in f(C)\} \supset C$$
and for $C\subset Y$
$$f(f^{-1}(C)) = \{f(x) | x\in \{y \in X | f(y) \in C\}\} \subset C$$
So note that the $C$ are subsets of two possibly different sets.

Example: $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto x^2$
Let $C = [0, 1)$ then $f(C) = [0, 1)$ and $f^{-1}(f(C)) = f^{-1}([0,1)) = (-1,1) \supset [0,1)$
Let $C = (-1, 1)$ then $f^{-1}(C) = (-1, 1)$ and $f(f^{-1}(C)) = f((-1,1)) = [0,1) \subset (-1,1)$